QCumber for unit testing in KDB
I'm trying to figure out how to use the qcumber unit-testing library.
I have src/ti.q
sma: {mavg[x; y]}; /simple moving average

and tests/sma.quke
feature sma
    before
        inputData: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
        expectedOutput: 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8;
        period: 5;
    should
        expect
            .qu.compare[expectedOutput; sma[period;inputData]]

I run the test via q $AXLIBRARIES_HOME/ws/qcumber.q_ -src ./src/ti.q -test ./tests -color -showAll which gives
Starting qCumber: q test runner

q)Loading src file: src/ti.q
Running tests: tests

file ti.quke
    feature sma
        (should)
            - fail | (expect)
                error: inputData (line 7)


Summary:
0 tests passed
0 benchmarks failed
1 tests failed
0 tests skipped

Clearly there is an issue with my tests/sma.quke file but I haven't been able to figure out how to pass in constants from the documentation at Testing framework for q(.qu). How do I get my expect block to see the variables defined in the before block (If indeed block is what's required)?

You need to set the variables in the before block as global variables, like:
feature sma
    before
        .test.inputData: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
        .test.expectedOutput: 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8;
        .test.period: 5;
    should
        expect
            .qu.compare[.test.expectedOutput; sma[.test.period;.test.inputData]]


I'm not sure if this is the preferred approach but I got things to work with,
feature sma
    should
        expect
        inputData: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
        expectedOutput: 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8;
        period: 5;
        .qu.compare[expectedOutput; sma[period;inputData]]

